# In MySQL, how to modify Partitioning definition?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Below is my MySQL creating table & if I want to modify the partition p7 to 350 & the rest in p8, is it possible? If it's possible, can anyone help me out, please?

```
CREATE TABLE `Site` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
  `status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
  `message` varchar(2000) DEFAULT NULL, 
  `createdOnDTime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
  `updatedOnDTime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
  `createdBy` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, 
  `updatedBy` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
) PARTITION BY RANGE (id) (
  PARTITION p1 
  VALUES 
    LESS THAN (50), 
    PARTITION p2 
  VALUES 
    LESS THAN (100), 
    PARTITION p3 
  VALUES 
    LESS THAN (150), 
    PARTITION p4 
  VALUES 
    LESS THAN (200), 
    PARTITION p5 
  VALUES 
    LESS THAN (250), 
    PARTITION p6 
  VALUES 
    LESS THAN (300), 
    PARTITION p7 
  VALUES 
    LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);
```

Comment: Actually there is no error message, is it possible to change the definition of the partition p7(to 350) & add p8(max value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to modify partitions.  This does require the partitions to be rebuilt, so there has to be space available for another copy, and the table will be locked while the partitions are rebuilt.

This can be fairly quick on empty or nearly empty partitions, but take a long time on big partitions. Other operations on the table will block while the partition operations are executing.

Before the operation, the partitions look like this

```
, PARTITION p6  VALUES LESS THAN (300)
, PARTITION p7  VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
)
```

We can execute a statement to "split" partition `p7` into two partitions, something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `Site` REORGANIZE PARTITION `p7` INTO 
( PARTITION `p7` VALUES LESS THAN (350)
, PARTITION `pmaxvalue` VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
) ;
```

after the operation completes, the partition definition will look something like

```
, PARTITION p6         VALUES LESS THAN (300)
, PARTITION p7         VALUES LESS THAN (350)
, PARTITION pmaxvalue  VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
)
```

Going forward, we can split the `pmaxvalue` partition again. This time, demonstrating a split into three partitions:

```
ALTER TABLE `Site` REORGANIZE PARTITION `pmaxvalue` INTO 
( PARTITION `p8` VALUES LESS THAN (400)
, PARTITION `p9` VALUES LESS THAN (450)
, PARTITION `pmaxvalue` VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
)
```

---

Syntax for the `REORGANIZE PARTITION`, and partition maintenance in general, is documented in the MySQL Reference Manual.

Comment: The answer was self-explanatory. Thanks a lot for that, I will try it out and keep you posted. - @spencer7593